# How to format html in windows phone 8.1 (universal) application for displaying it in RichTextBlock control?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1

How to format / convert html in windows phone 8.1 (universal) application for displaying it in RichTextBlock control?

I was using HtmlAgilityPack in Windows Phone Silverlight application to parse / convert html content to display it in RichTextBox.

How can we achieve the same in windows phone 8.1 (universal app)?

Or do we have any other control like Webview to display HTML content in windows phone 8.1 (universal app)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display HTML content in your (universal) app, then WebView is the way to go, since it supports both platforms. From what I've seen so far, you can either load a page by a URI or specify the HTML as a string.
Here's a basic sample: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/webview-control-in-windows-store-apps-using-C-Sharpxaml/

This might also be helpful, as there are some points what the control will NOT do: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx